# How to increment an Integer variable by X without creating a new object instance

Tags: ruby

How can I increment an Integer variable by X without creating a new object instance?

`+=` does not work because:

```
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > x = 1
1
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > x.object_id
3
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > x += 1
2
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > x.object_id
5
```

Comment: Are you asking out of curiosity, or is there a use case for this (such as concurrent programming)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Not in Ruby, and not in any other programming language I am aware of.

The object which represents the mathematical number `1` will *always* have the value `1`. Mutating the object which represents the mathematical number `1` to suddenly have the value `2` would quite simply be insane, because now all of a sudden `1 + 1 == 4`.

Comment: And what's wrong with `1 + 1 == 4`? They do it in government and corporations all the time! :-)

Comment: You can mutate this in Python and I would guess also in Ruby - also this answer completely fails to address why this is the case. Consider the difference `a=12; b=12; b.object_id; a.object_id;` vs `(x = 9**57; y= 9**57; y.object_id; x.object_id)`

Answer (score 2):

Extend your example for a moment.  Try this:

```
x = 2
y = 1 + 1

x.object_id
y.object_id
```

Every unique number will have its own identity.  Ruby's object orientedness goes a bit deeper than you will find with C++ and Java (both of those have the concept of primitives and classes).

What's important is that when you query `x` the second time for its *value* the value will be what you expect.  Object identifiers don't really matter unless you are the garbage collector.

Comment: In YARV ruby, `x` and `y` both have `object_id`s of 5. Are they different to each other in your implementation?

Comment: That was the point.  The value 2 will have the same instance id, regardless of how you got there.  In the end, object ids mean nothing--it's the variable you care about.

Answer (score 0):

It gets worse with `Bignum`s

```
begin
  a = 1234567890
  puts a.object_id
  b = 1234567890
  puts b.object_id
end
```

gave me

```
10605136
10604960
```

Answer (score 0):

Execution time is really terrible even if just you organize a simple loop. Primitives shouldn't be ditched from Ruby.

```
(1..16000).each do
  (1..16000).each do
  end
end
```

This itself takes 30-40 seconds to complete (Lenovo T400, Virtualboxed Ubuntu), and you haven't even done something sophisticated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper class:

```
class Variable
  def initialize value = nil
    @value = value
  end

  attr_accessor :value

  def method_missing *args, &blk
    @value.send(*args, &blk)
  end

  def to_s
    @value.to_s
  end

  # here's the increment/decrement part
  def inc x = 1
    @value += x
  end

  def dec x = 1
    @value -= x
  end
end

x = Variable.new 1
puts x               #=> 1
puts x.object_id     #=> 22456116 (or whatever)

x.inc
puts x               #=> 2
puts x.object_id     #=> 22456116

x.inc 3
puts x               #=> 5
puts x.object_id     #=> 22456116
```

More uses of "class Variable" [here](http://rubychallenger.blogspot.com/2011/03/class-variable-to-increment-fixnum.html).