# Misunderstanding about Object#tap

Tags: ruby

Here is my simple test code:

```
def test_function
  0.tap do |v|
    v += 10
  end
end

p test_function
```

Why I get 0 here ? I was waiting to get 10.

**Update:**

```
class TestClass
    def initialize
        @v = 0
    end

    def inc 
        @v = @v + 1
    end
end

def test_function
    0.tap do |v|
        v += 10
    end
end

def test_function_2
    TestClass.new.tap { |obj|
        obj.inc
    }
end

p test_function
p test_function_2
```

> 0
>
> TestClass:0x29244f0 @v=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is that the original object is not changed by the += operator. So what happens it that you create a reference to it in the block, change the reference to point to an other object, which is larger by 10 and then return. the value of 0 stays the same.

And thing about it -- this is what you want to happen. The += operator does not change the object it operates on. It returns *another different* object and assigns the reference to it. This is like:

```
  v = 0
  v = v + 10
```

You wouldn't expect `0 == 10` to be true after this, right?

Comment: Thanks, I think I undertand. Next question, is there any ability to change value of Integer object without create a new object ?

Comment: I don't think so. This would make confusing things such as (0==10)==true possible. See here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Fixnum.html

Comment: The reason += returns a new object is that all integers are in fact different objects, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256228/how-can-i-increment-an-integer-variable-by-x-without-creating-a-new-object-insta

Answer (score 4):

There is additional answer here: The method `tap` returns the original object. You can use it e.g. for side-effects, like reporting, collecting stats or logging. It doesn't give you extra under-the-hood access to the original object.

```
v = [0,1,2]
v.tap { |array| array.map { |x| x + 1 } }
=> [0,1,2]

v.tap { |array| array.map! { |x| x + 1 } }
=> [1,2,3]
```

A variant of your test_function_2 could be used, where an object that you control has an Integer property, even just an array with one element:

```
def test_function
  [0].tap do |v|
    v[0] += 10
  end
end

p test_function[0]
=> 10
```

. . . depends what you are trying to do?